# Line breaks in CSV row

Tags: regex, xml, csv, xslt, calabash

I've the following csv

```
DATO;JOBSID;JOBNR;TEKST;AFSENDER;MODTAGER
02-06-2017;1234;4321;"MEI KONG ML KL. 00.45-13.00 TLF. NR 1023 0188
SØNDAG ML KL 24.00-11.00 TLF. NR. 6935 0188
Prags Boulevard 49D.  Tlf. 3134 5998
Bogpakker: Tlf. 1245 0880
TILLIDSREPRÆSENTANT GRETE WISE: TLF. 21200919";"DI";"ALLE"
```

Initially I was using the newline character for row tokenization. But my data also contains line breaks, and I needed to maintain those line breaks. I've tried to replace the line break with a special character and later replace that with the line break. But in this scenario I'm not able to tokenize.

My XSLT is as following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:f="foo/bar"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:include href="job-lib.xsl"/><!-- string normalization and other general functions in this library -->

    <!-- Parameters -->
    <xsl:param name="csv-file"/><!-- the input csv file -->
    <xsl:param name="text-encoding" as="xs:string" select="'iso-8859-1'"/>
    <xsl:param name="root-element"/><!-- root element name in output file -->

    <!-- The direct input to the transformation is an "empty" xml file with (empty) root element "null" -->
    <xsl:template match="null">
        <xsl:variable name="output-file" select="concat(substring-before($csv-file,'.csv'),'.xml')"/>
            <xsl:element name="{$root-element}">
                <xsl:variable name="csv-content">
                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text($csv-file,$text-encoding),'&#xD;')">
                        <xsl:element name="row">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="column-names" select="tokenize(string($csv-content/row[1]),';')"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$csv-content/row[position() &gt; 1]">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(string(.),';')">
                            <xsl:variable name="column-pos" select="position()"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="element-name" select="$column-names[$column-pos]"/>
                            <xsl:element name="{$element-name}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="f:normalize(.)"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required XML is

```
<job>
  <row>
    <DATO>02-06-2017</DATO>
    <JOBSID>1234</JOBSID>
    <JOBNR>4321</JOBNR>
    <TEKST>
      "MEI KONG ML KL. 00.45-13.00 TLF. NR 1023 0188
      MEI KONG ML KL 24.00-11.00 TLF. NR. 6935 0188
      Prags Boulevard 49D.  Tlf. 3134 5998
      Bogpakker: Tlf. 1245 0880
      TILLIDSREPRÆSENTANT GRETE WISE: TLF. 21200919
    </TEKST>
    <AFSENDER>DI</AFSENDER>
    <MODTAGER>ALLE</MODTAGER>
   </row>
</job>
```

Please help me, how can I convert my CSV into the required XML format which contains the line breaks as well.

I'm using calabash for the conversion.

Comment: [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using XSLT for this? There are other, more appropriate, tools for parsing delimited text.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me if your sample data is representative.  If your actual data is fully consistent with your sample data, then a simple fix might be possible -- your `MODTAGER` string is the last data field in each record, and that string ends in `"\n`.  Meanwhile, your `TEKST` string, the only data field that contains newlines, never has a newline immediately preceded by a double quote -- so `"\n` would never match anything in the `TEKST` string.  You could thus safely tokenize on `"\n` to break the file up by each individual record.